# npx create react project hangs

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

Hi when ever I try to use npx create-react-app *appname*, the process hangs and stalls at
reify:fsevents: sill reify mark deleted. What could be the cause and how to resolve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiO6l.png)

I tried clearing the cache and reinstalled node.js but that has not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried npm cache clean --force to clear cache and did not work,

Try Using --ignore-scripts: Sometimes, skipping the installation of fsevents can resolve the issue. You can try running the create-react-app command with the --ignore-scripts flag like so:

npx create-react-app appname --ignore-scripts